# Ubuntu guest OS display is not fitting to screen in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, display

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGEEF.jpg)I have ubuntu OS runnning in virtualbox. When ubuntu starts it does not fit to the screen in fact it is bigger than the display and I need to use scroll bar to navigate to clock and shutdown button on right top corner.

I have latest guest additions installed. Check the versions below.

host OS : windows 7 virtualbox : 5.0.18 guest os : ubuntu 14.04.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused when oracle virtualbox software version and guest additions **version are different**. 
If you see any of the screen fitting issues make sure that versions of virtualbox software and guest additions are same.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbrmr.png)

In the Virtualbox Menubar, Navigate to 'View' and Click on 'Auto-resize Guest Display'.
Make sure the Vbox Guest Additions are installed.